# redirect users to another server from one server

Tags: redirect, users

Hai guys,
  I have domain registered say www.example.com in a server... I forgot the server details (everything) related to that domain... It was hosted by another person and he is out of contact right now... Now i want to redirect my users to www.example.in when they hit www.example.com.... Is it possible ?  Are any other suggestions because i dont know where www.example.com is hosted,done by whom,emailId used while reg... Please help me out guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could only do this by changing the domain's nameservers (requires having edit access to the registrar's information for the domain), or changing the content of the nameserver records (requires having access to the nameservers). (Or, of course, having access to the actual server, but you said you don't.)

If you don't control the domain registration of www.example.com (which is what I *think* you mean by "... i dont know where www.example.com is hosted,done by whom,emailId used while reg..."), and you don't control the nameservers, then you're basically asking how to hijack a domain that isn't under your control. Your specific situation may be benign, but even if there are ways to do it, I don't think any responsible member of serverfault.com would want to publish techniques for doing so that could be misused by someone else reading them.

You'll have to wait until you can contact the person who does have control of the domain and work things out with him.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control webserver running the old domain, or at least can access it, you can use redirecting capabilities of it to redirect it (eg. mod_redirect in Apache). With a little luck you can do this in .htaccess file without need to reconfigure the server.

If you don't have access to the server at all and you can not control DNS records, there is no way other than waiting for the other person.

Answer (score 0):

If you control webserer running the old domain you can modify the home page to redirect to new domain.
PHP:
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com");

ASP:
Response.Redirect "http://www.newdomain.com"

Answer (score 0):

This really needs to be done in DNS, not on a web server. If you don't know how to do that contact your domain registrar and discuss the problem with them and they should be able to guide you.